# Filter out 'None' from Python list, 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, exception, typeerror

My script does an LDAP search:

```
import ldap
...<initializations>
res = conn.search_s(base, scope_level, filter, attrs)
_logger.debug("LDAP query result: %s", res)

# Filter out the 'None' entries for referrals
filter(lambda x: (isinstance(x,tuple) and x[0] is not None), res)
```

This filter here errors out with `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

I added `try...except` around it to log `_logger.debug("Result was:%s, Result type: %s", res, type(res))` and it is indeed a list

```
# Example:
Result was:[('CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=hiccups,DC=com',
{'sAMAccountName': ['domain admins']}),
(None, ['ldap://sirius.hiccups.com/DC=sirius,DC=hiccups,DC=com']),
(None, ['ldap://ForestDnsZones.hiccups.com/DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=hiccups,DC=com']),
(None, ['ldap://DomainDnsZones.hiccups.com/DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=hiccups,DC=com']),
(None, ['ldap://hiccups.com/CN=Configuration,DC=hiccups,DC=com'])],
Result type: <type 'list'>
```

If I copy the list in a separate script and run the same filter, it works as expected.

A `for` construct replacing `filter` also works fine:

```
result = []
for each in res:
if (isinstance(each, tuple) and each[0] is not None):
    result.append(each)
```

But I want to debug why `filter` is failing

Comment: Have you reassigned the `filter` keyword?

Comment: Ah, good point. Let me check !!

Comment: Yups, that was it. The method was accepting `filter` as LDAP filter parameter. Someone committed this change recently :) That is why I ask my peers to not use `vim` and instead use some python IDE ;)

Comment: @mittal: Otherwise you could tell that peer to fix his/her vim so that it shows these kind of errors :P

Comment: @101 One of you please make an answer to get this question out of the list of unanswereds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was suggested by @101's comment, `filter` keyword was being used a parameter name too in the same method where I was observing issue.

The `filter` parameter was a string, hence the `TypeError`

Simply changed the parameter name to `ldap_filter` to fix it